# jquery ui resizable remove re-add element and keep resizable effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an element that is resizable thanks to:

```
$("#myelement").resizable();
```

If I remove the element from the DOM using `$("#myelement").remove()`

then re-add it, the resizable effect does not work anymore. I have to reinitialize it. Is there a way to keep it and not have to reinitialize it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.detach()` instead of `remove()`

The `detach()` method is the same as `remove()`, except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements.

http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 0):

No, when you use the remove() method, that destroys the element completely.  Why are you removing it and re-adding it?  You should wrap the method that sets up the element in a function, and when you re-add it call the method.